# Proper way to implement custom View and dynamically added children

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, horizontalscrollview

I'm extending a HorizontalScrollView. This layout will add children to a LinearLayout when the public `setItems` method is called. These children views are **dynamically inflated** and their widths depend on the parent (fill parent when only one view, and 1/2 parent when >= 2 items).

```
<!-- custom_layout.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Sometimes, `setItems` is called in a callback of a network request, so the layout might already be fully inflated. Where should I be calling `updateView` which needs the parent's width and to add inflated children? I put the call in both `onSizeChanged` and `setItems` like below.

```
public class CustomLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

    private LinearLayout container; 
    private List<Item> items;

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
        updateView();
    }

    public CustomLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        View v = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_layout, this);
        container = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.container);
        updateView();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        updateView();
    }

    public void updateView() {
        if (items == null) {
            return;
        }

        container.removeAllViews();

        int width = getWidth();
        if (items.size() > 1) {
            width = width * 1 / 2;
        }

        for (final Item item : items) {        
            View child = LayoutInflator.from(getContext(), R.layout.custom_item, container, false);                   
            child.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            container.addView(child);
        }
    }

}
```

I don't know why this way does not always work. Sometimes, the child, `container` just fails to render for some reason. Seeing the layout hierarchy shows that HorizontalScrollView has no children. What happened to `container`?

Also, it seems that even when placed in a network call, `setItems` is called **before** `onSizeChanged`, which makes me think that `onSizeChanged` is the wrong place to do `updateView`?

Comment: I don't think you need to call `updateView` on `onSizeChanged`. Just call invalidate on `updateView` or `setItems`. On another note, I think you should use `RecyclerView` with a horizontal layout manager. You would can do the same thing, just easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the `updateView()` method inside `onMeasure` instead of `onSizeChanged`, and use `getMeasuredWidth()` instead of `getWidth()`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    updateView();
}

public void updateView() {
    if (items == null) {
        return;
    }

    container.removeAllViews();

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    if (items.size() > 1) {
        width = width * 1 / 2;
    }

    for (final Item item : items) {        
        View child = LayoutInflator.from(getContext(), R.layout.custom_item, container, false);                   
        child.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        container.addView(child);
    }
}
```

Also, if you call `setItems()` method from callback of async request, dont forget to run it on UI thread by using `runOnUiThread` method of `Activity`.